# Emacs Helm Swoop error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: $buf"

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I get an elisp error when I select a match from helm swoop (by pressing enter):

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: $buf
```

Is this a known bug in the current version of helm swoop or might I have something misconfigured?

Comment: This issue(https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/pull/80) was already fixed. Please update and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I searched this problem from [Github Issues](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/pull/80) so its quite new problem. It's fixed and merged to Melpa 9 days ago.

As you know just write `list-packages` and press `U` and `X`

Best Regards